# pyModis createMosaicGDAL AttributeError

Tags: python, modis, mosaic, attributeerror, pymodis

I've been playing around with the [convertmodis_gdal module](http://www.pymodis.org/pymodis/convertmodis_gdal.html) in pyModis. I've successfully downloaded HDFs, but I've run into a wall mosaicking them.

The following is what I've posted on the pyModis GitHub under "Issues":

> The code I've written:
>
> ```
> hdf_list = ['D:/MODIS/MCD18A1.A2020001.h10v03.061.2020350135843.hdf',
>             'D:/MODIS/MCD18A1.A2020001.h11v03.061.2020350135958.hdf',
>            ]
>
> modis_mosaic = pymodis.convertmodis_gdal.createMosaicGDAL(
>     hdfnames = hdf_list,
>     subset = False,
>     outformat = 'GTiff'
>     )
>
> modis_mosaic.run('D:/MODIS/mosaic_file')
> ```
>
> The error I get:
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pymodis_project\modis_download.py",
> line 54, in <module> 
> modis_mosaic.run('mosaic_file')
>
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\pymodis\lib\site-packages\pymodis\convertmodis_gdal.py",
> line 619, in run
> self.write_mosaic_xml(output)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\pymodis\lib\site-packages\pymodis\convertmodis_gdal.py",
> line 591, in write_mosaic_xml
> pmm.writexml("%s.xml" % prefix)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\pymodis\lib\site-packages\pymodis\parsemodis.py",
> line 982, in writexml 
> self.valMeasuredParameter(mpc)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\pymodis\lib\site-packages\pymodis\parsemodis.py",
> line 821, in valMeasuredParameter 
> for val in i.retMeasure().values():
>
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\pymodis\lib\site-packages\pymodis\parsemodis.py",
> line 208, in retMeasure 
> for i in meStat.iter():
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iter'
> ```
>
> I assume the issue is with what I've written for "subset"? I'm trying
> to mosaic all of the data together, not just one or two bands. I've
> tried specifying subsets anyway, but it still doesn't work.
>
> I'm using Python 3.8.18, pyModis 2.3.0, and GDAL 3.8.2.